# CUPS wont start on LTSP client

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cups, ltsp

I have attempted to install CUPS on an LTSP fat client.  Both the client and the server are running Ubuntu 9.10 and cups runs fine on the server.  When I try to start it on a client I get this:

```
root@ltsp52:~# service cups start  
* Starting Common Unix Printing System: cupsd  
/usr/sbin/cupsd: error while loading shared libraries: libcupsmime.so.1:  
cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory  
                                                                     [ OK ]  
root@ltsp52:~#
```

`libcupsmime.so.1` exists in `/usr/lib/libcupsmime.so.1` (the same place it exists on the server).  I'm not quite sure what I am doing wrong, but the problem is becoming quite frustrating and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: We have an LTSP setup with CUPS and I don't see that file on either system.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try a `# sudo aptitude install libcupsmime1 libcupsmime1-dev` on both boxes

Comment: I had to downgrade to 9.04 since I couldn't get this figured out so I can't test your answer, but I had libcupsmime1 installed already and it didn't help.  I'm not sure about libcupsmime1-dev.  I think it is a bug with that version of CUPS.  It works fine on 9.04 and 10.04.  I appreciate the help though.